# Compilation failed in require when using "use" in Perl

Tags: eclipse, perl, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am using Perl in Eclipse.

In the same directory, I have a `.pl` file and two `.pm` files (pmFile1.pm, pmFile2.pm).

At the top of the .pl file, I use the command:

```
use pmFile1;
use pmFile2;
```

I get an error

> Compilation failed in require

I do not believe I had this error earlier. I have researched this error online, and cannot figure out what may have caused it, because I have not found a similar situation to mine that caused the error. I do not know what other information would be pertinent to include, but will add anything if asked...

Thank you.

Comment: What is the full error? Are there any other warning messages? Can you show a minimal version of your modules that reproduces the errors?

Comment: @amon, I believe that actually is the entire message shown by EPIC for this particular problem. It's very annoying! (Note that EPIC uses PPI to do syntax highlighting, producing extremely accurate results, and very Perl-like error messages, but not necessarily actual Perl messages.)

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was the entire warning. I am trying to think of a way to show the modules (and by that, do you mean the .pm files... sorry for naivety)

Comment: Do you get any errors from `perl -Mlib=/Users/rotatingstudent/Desktop/Stella/Meta/code -e'use pmFile1;'`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I get: syntax error at -e line 1, near "use pmFile1."
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: One other strange thing is that I believe this was all working recently when I only had one module. Then, when I added the second module, they both started showing the error (whichever module was first in the program would have it). I could be wrong, but I do not recall changing much else...

Comment: err, that was supposed to have been "use pmFile1;", not "use pmFile1.".

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in `pmFile.pm`. Can you share the code with us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you **check the module** pmFile1.pm for errors in a terminal shell

```
$ perl -c pmFile1.pm
syntax error at pmFile1.pm line 1, near "."
pmFile1.pm had compilation errors.
```

When entering a single dot . as a syntax error into pmFile1.pm and running the p.pl file then the errors below are shown in Eclipse, the same as you described. If you run the .pl file in a terminal shell then you get the same *compilation failed in require* as in eclipse:

```
$ perl p.pl
syntax error at pmFile1.pm line 1, near "."
Compilation failed in require at p.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at p.pl line 1.
```

[image: EPIC output on syntax error]

Answer (score 2):

This may not be your problem, but I've been "bitten" by something similar before: check the End of Line chars in the file. It may be that your code is seen by the compiler to be all one line, making an error anywhere in the code appear as being on line 1 when visually (in the editor) the offending line would be later in the code. In notepad++ you resolve this sort of issue by using the Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows Format (or whatever format is correct for you) menu option, though other editors will likely have a similar feature for *NIX <-> Windows EOL conversions. This error would make sense if you can successfully use the module files giving you an error without errors in other script files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the required package to some dummy name, then retaining it.